# ascii conversion to form alphabet

Tags: python

any way to come up with: Aa Bb.....=>Zz? using def, loop..

lot of errors here:

```
for i in range(65,70):
    for j in range(97,102):
        print("    ",(chr(i)), (chr(j)),end = '')

for a in range(70,76):
    for b in range(103,108):
        print("    ",(chr(a)), (chr(b)),end = '')
for c in range(76,82):
    for d in range(109,114):
        print("    ",(chr(c)), (chr(d)),end ='')
for e in range(82,88):
    for f in range(115,120):
        print("    ",(chr(e)), (chr(f)),end = '')

for g in range(88,91):
    for h in range(121,123):
        print("    ",(chr(g)), (chr(h)),end ='')
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to substitute each A-Z, a-z letter with the letter that is 25 later in the alphabet?

Comment: yes I am..                                                        Aa Bb Cc Dd Ee Ff                                                       Gg Hh..  should look like that of multiplication table  somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modules string and the function zip to achieve this :

```
import string
result = ""
for upper, lower in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase):
    result = result + upper + lower + " "

print result
```

It gives `Aa Bb Cc Dd Ee Ff Gg Hh Ii Jj Kk Ll Mm Nn Oo Pp Qq Rr Ss Tt Uu Vv Ww Xx Yy Zz`

---

**Edit**

As pointed and measured by @PM 2Ring, using `join` is faster than affecting the result every time.
So you can use the following which will be faster :

```
result = ' '.join([u + l for u, l in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase)])
```

Even though it is bit less readable.
I would also recommend not using `chr` and the ascii codes for a better readability unless of course you have other reasons do to so.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference for a short string like this, but generally calling the `str.join()` method on a list (or other iterable) is more efficient than concatenating strings using `+`. Strings are immutable in Python; when you do `result = result + some_string` new memory has to be allocated for the new `result` and the old one gets thrown away.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for pointing out, i'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Everything is done in the line `result = result + upper + lower` and insert a space where you like. For the join part, juste join on a space rather than an empty string. You could have figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop from `ord('A')` to `ord('Z')` included, outputing the upper and lower case letter. Something like :

```
letters = ''
for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1) :
    letters = letters + chr(i) + chr(i + 32)
print letters
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions to easily do this ...

```
import operator
print reduce( operator.add ,[ ' '+chr(i+65)+chr(i+97) for i in range(26)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python module `string` contains various ASCII alphabetic strings. You can use it like this to get the string you want.

```
' '.join([chr(i+65) + chr(i+97) for i in range(26)])
```

But if you don't want to use that module you can use this list comprehension:

```
' '.join([chr(i+65)+chr(i+97) for i in range(26)])
```

Here's some timing data for various approaches:

```
$ timeit.py -n 10000 -s 'import string' "' '.join([u+v for u, v in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase)])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.7 usec per loop

$ timeit.py -n 10000 "' '.join([chr(i+65)+chr(i+97) for i in range(26)])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.4 usec per loop

$ timeit.py -n 10000 "''.join([' '+chr(i+65)+chr(i+97) for i in range(26)])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 50.6 usec per loop

$ timeit.py -n 10000 "letters=''" "for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1):letters = letters + chr(i) + chr(i + 32) + ' '"
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.6 usec per loop

$ timeit.py -n 10000 -s 'from operator import add' "reduce(add, [' '+chr(i+65)+chr(i+97) for i in range(26)])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.3 usec per loop
```

As you can see, the `zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase)` approach is *definitely* the fastest way to do this.